# Spring test(Junit) is failed in maven command, but successed in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: spring, maven, unit-testing

What I got from maven process is below:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [class org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I did search from Google, sounds like the spring dependency version issue, but I am using the same version (4.3.5) for all spring libs.

It's working in IDE when I run the test classes individually.

anybody have this issue before?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: Have you check if you don't have more dependencies in your classpath within your IDE, sometimes the IDE import automatically some libraries

Comment: I checked, they are same.